# Store row values from dropdown selection in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to store all the row values from the table(maybe in an array?) when a selection is made in the dropdown so I can via column name retrieve any value from the choosen row.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<label for="select"><select name="id" value="Select" size="1" onChange="this.form.submit()"> 
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE matningstyp ='odb'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
        $namn=$row["namn"]; 
        $foretag=$row["foretag"];  
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$foretag\">".$namn; 
} 
?> 
        <option>
        <? echo $options ?>
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your code again, I think you've made some mistake.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
    <label for="select">
    <select name="id">
           <?php 
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE matningstyp ='odb'";  
                  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                          echo "<option value='".$row['foretag']."'>".$row['namn']."</option>";
                  } 
           ?> 
    </select>
</form>
```

It's shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure though on how to proceed. Lets say I want to show the value in column "key1" from that row choosen in the dropdown? How do I go about doing that? I'm a supernewbie so I'm sorry if this should be obvious!

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<label for="your_select"><select id="your_select" name="id" onChange="this.form.submit()"> 
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE matningstyp ='odb'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
        $namn=$row["namn"]; 
        $foretag=$row["foretag"];  
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$foretag\">".$namn.'</option>';
} 
?> 
        <? echo $options ?>
    </select>
</form>
```